# HTML/CSS Text is not showing in DIV/P

Tags: html, css

I have something like this

```
<div class="top"><p class="title">Some text</p></div>
```

and a CSS for it

```
.title {
    text-align: center;
    color:blue;
}

.top {
    width:1205px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url("Tlo_top.png");
    color: blue;   
}
```

And it just does not show the text which is strange because it worked before i added the background but now when i remove it it still does not show it O.o

Comment: did you try to remove the color attribute from one of them ?

Comment: Why is tagged php? o.o

Comment: Yes i tried 
And for the tag i am sorry i didnt notice that

Comment: I would say the background image is covering your text. Have you tried to inspect your element with the developer tools?

Comment: Float not cleared? Without a demo it's hard to comment as we can't see the problem.

Comment: Here is a demo. The text is there. http://jsfiddle.net/dro06r26/ Need to scroll right the output.

Comment: Probably this is not the only code. This code is valid (http://jsfiddle.net/o4Lx4e00/) and you will see the text. Can you give us more code?

Comment: Text is clearly visible in the link too!

Comment: try clear your cache, because text is on top

Comment: `<LINK rel=stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css">` change to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">` because its not loading the css here

Comment: Yup when i go thrue link i can see the text and when i just refresh  allready opened site it does not   sorry for trouble and thank you all for help

Answer (score 0):

Text is showing even i added background image please check the fiddle,
   http://jsfiddle.net/nikkirs/xnmd53c2/
May be your text color and image color are same

```
.title
{
text-align: center;
color:blue;
}

.top
{
width:1205px;
height:100px;
float:left;
background:#000000;
color: blue;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
div {
    background: url(img_flwr.gif);
    background-size: 80px 60px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was cashe affter i cleared it the text was showing.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="top">
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.top {
  width:1205px;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
  background-image: url("Tlo_top.png");
  color: blue;
}
.top p {
  text-align: center;
  color:blue;
}
```

Try this. Its working fine for me. If still not working, may be the same text color and image color could be the problem.